# Contact Form plugin email is not being received, not clear if it is being sent

Tags: templating, plugin-contactform

I am using the Pixel & Tonic Contact Form plugin.  I set it up using the Mijingo tutorial.  Everything appears to be working ...

I hit submit, redirects to thank you, no message received.  Setup looks good.  Hidden input fields appear good.  Error messages working when required inputs (`fromEmail` and `message`) left blank.  Redirects to thank you.  Honeypot setup looks good.   But, **no message received.  And I don't know how to confirm it is really being sent.  What might I try? Thanks**

I am in dev mode

Answer (score 3):

There's a good article here for troubleshooting email errors and well as email deliverability issues: https://craftcms.com/support/troubleshooting-email-errors

TL/DR: Don't use PHP's mail/sendmail methods in production and even in development, you aren't guaranteed email deliverability with those.

Answer (score 1):

Are you testing in a local environment? If you don't have a mail server configured then PHP won't be able to send the email.

Comment: Yes that is correct.  Now the noob question - will this work real-world as is?

Comment: Haven't seen your code, but if it's set up properly; yes.